# how to get wp plugin url with echo in variable?

Tags: wordpress, variables

I'm working on a plugins in wordpress. I want to push some data in my database

I d like to get someting like this for my logos:

```
$logoname = "<img src='".$pluginlocation."".$name.".gif'>";
```

with something like that (that, which does not work) :

```
$pluginlocation = echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'/image' ;
```

tx ;)

Comment: $pluginlocation = echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'/image' ;

Comment: nope, cant get the value : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in xxx.php on line 49

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
<?php
echo '<img src="' . plugins_url( 'images/your_image_name.gif', dirname(__FILE__) ) . '" > ';
?>
```

for more detail on this please refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: I need it for a variable cause i use this variable in a Select INSERT..